# GSAP directional rotations plugins do not work with PIXI plugins

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixi.js, gsap

I am trying to use directional rotation plugins together with pixi.js plugins.

However, it doesn't seem to be working. If you undo the comments in the codepen: https://codepen.io/asiankingofwhales/pen/RyNKBR?editors=0010, you could see that I tried three different ways:

```
1  directly adding "_cw" doesn't work

2. using directional rotation plugin without pixi.js plugin result in crazy rotating

3. combining directional rotation plugin with pixi plugin doesn't work at all. no rotations.
```

Can anyone help?

**Or if this is not possible yet, can anyone shed some lights on how to do directional rotations with pixi.js**?

This is the simplified versions of a project I am working on: https://codepen.io/asiankingofwhales/pen/JvoWYY?editors=0010. Basically, I have a constantly rotating object, then at one point, I decide to rotate it to a certain point. However, I want all the rotations to be clockwise, which isn't possible at this point.

I tried accessing the current rotations values, and then calculate the difference between the current and the destination values, then using the "=+" to do clockwise rotation. However, the value I am accessing always seems to be outdated.

Because if the rectangle is constantly rotating, I might be getting a rotation value now, but by the time I used it to calculate differences, it's already moving to a bigger rotational angle. Or am i wrong?

Any other other solutions to this problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer has been found:

https://greensock.com/forums/topic/18213-directional-rotations-do-not-work-with-pixi-plugins/?tab=comments#comment-83923